# undefined method `save!' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> Did you mean? save_btn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Below is my code can any one knows why is this error. This regular code works in other cases but not in below case.

```
    @item_assistance_register = Office::ItemAssistanceRegister.new
    @item_assistance_register.office_id = current_office.id
    @item_assistance_register.user_id = current_user.id
    @item_assistance_register.personnel_id = personnel_id
    @item_assistance_register.register_page_no = new_item_assistance_register_page_no
    @item_assistance_register.save!
    @item_assistance_register
  end
```

Here is my model

```
class Office::ItemAssistanceRegister < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_assistance_register_items, class_name: "Office::ItemAssistanceRegisterItem", dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :personnel, class_name: "Office::Personnel"
  belongs_to :office, :class_name => 'Office::Office'
  # belongs_to :fiscal_year, :class_name => 'Office::FiscalYear'
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Need more details. What type of Object is `Office::ItemAssistanceRegister` AR or ARel. The error message says it is a ARel. If so then save wont work on it.

Comment: @AlokSwain, I have updated may code. Please look at this.

Comment: is `@item_assistance_register` an instance of `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @item_assistance_register is a relation while it should be model. Can you please provide office::ItemAssistanceRegister code

Comment: Please have a look.